# Beamer and Ua Language

Tags: beamer, languages

Does Beamer work with Ukranian language? I try to use it several times and all bad :)

If you have working project share with me, please!)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I try to add my code but it's too large...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell (without being able to read anything) it seems to work fine with `babel`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Привіт Світ
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I try to compile this code and have empty DVI. Can you help me? Why I have this problem?

Comment: @Taraas Can you try to compile with `pdflatex` to directly obtain a pdf?

Comment: Oo! Thanks! I try to create presentation and will ask about problems!